# I want to download file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

on this way i can upload image and pdf..
but i want to download the pdf or image from my view...please someone give me the code of downloading pdf or image from view..give me the full code

```
 public function save_about_1() {
    $about_1_image_info = $this->w_model->select_about_1_image();
    $image_path = explode(base_url(), $about_1_info->about_1_link, 2);
    unlink($image_path[1]);
    $this->sa_model->delete_about_1($about_1_info->about_1_id);
    $data = array();
    /* Uplod start */
    $config['upload_path'] = 'images/about_1/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|doc|xml';
    $config[ 'overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['max_size'] = '10000kb';
    $config['max_width'] = '100240';
    $config['max_height'] = '76800';
    $error = array();
    $fdata = array();
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('about_1_link')) {
        $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $edata = array();
        $edata['error_message'] = $error;
        $this->session->set_userdata($edata);
        redirect('super_admin/about_1');
    } else {
        $fdata = $this->upload->data();
        $data['about_1_link'] = base_url() . $config['upload_path'] . $fdata['file_name'];
        $this->sa_model->save_about_1_info($data);
        $sdata = array();
        $sdata['message'] = "Saved Image Successfully";
        $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);
        redirect('super_admin/about_1');
    }
}
```

Comment: try download attr <a href="YOUR_PATH" download></a>

Comment: what should i write in my controller?my image folder name is about_1...i m very confused!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CI download helper for this.

```
$data = file_get_contents("/path/to/photo.jpg"); // Read the file's contents
$name = 'myphoto.jpg';

force_download($name, $data);
```

From the CI User Guide.
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/download_helper.html